# How long does it take to get from Moat Cailin to Mole Town on horseback?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, time, geography

Question says it all. How long does it take to get from Moat Cailin to Mole Town on horseback?

Assumptions:

- No battles are going on, but the land is not peaceful.
- You need to not attract too much attention, but you're not a wanted man.
- You're rich (horse changes an option?)
- You're riding with either 1 or 2 companions, no more.
- It's early winter.

Comment: I approved the edits to my answer because you are the OP, but are spoiler tags really needed?

Comment: @Skooba: I would think so... I didn't ask about anyone specific, right?

Comment: This is true. I will leave them. I guess spoiler tags, can't *hurt* an answer.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's about two weeks from Winterfell to Moat Callin. I am not so sure about how long it takes people usually to get from Winterfell to the wall. I believe its somewhere between 2 and 3 weeks. Everything is want I think I remember from the books, so I'm not making this an answer.

Comment: You should know that when it comes to GRRM, trying to count days and make inferences from timeline with that is useless. He has admitted it himself that time and geography does not always add up 100%.

Comment: @TLP: Maybe that's true for the war of the usurper, or other conflicting historical threads, but in the alluded-to case, which I shall not describe due to spoilers, it's just one person and a bunch of people twiddling their thumbs waiting for him apparently. Also, GRRM doesn't write the show...

Answer (score 7):

Judging from [this map](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/images/e/e7/Map_of_westeros.jpg) is approximately +/- 1,000 miles from Moat Cailin to Castle Black and Mole's Town is *just* to the south.

You might be able to get [100 miles per day](http://www.ask.com/pets-animals/far-can-horse-travel-one-day-bf5864aa50254c85) out the best horses, if you have access to them.

> and I am sure Littlefinger had such access.

This would put the journey at **around 10 days, maybe a fortnight** if we assume a bit slower pace. Changing mounts would always be an option too if one travels on the King's Road.

> This is reasonable if Littlefinger left when he heard Sansa had escaped, and not when he 100% proof she made it to Castle Black. The fighting in the North has died down since the Red Wedding. Stannis' defeat was the last major battle.
>
> A rider making the trip would not have to worry about standing armies. (just have to avoid Winterfell), but I doubt Littlefinger rode alone.

Even with a few guards the 100 mile/day pace could be kept.

Comment: Actually, the source you cited suggests that the daily figure is more like 20-31 miles. This is not the "Pony Express". The horse changing would be necessary, apparently, even for a daily 30 miles. So let's make that a 5 week journey on the Kings' Road.

Comment: The way, I took it, the 30 miles was mounted soldiers.

Comment: I don't suppose you happen to have any real life experience with this stuff?

Comment: @Skooba - I know precious little of the equestrian arts, but I'd think that endurance would be the ruling factor here rather than speed, which is something humans are adapted to.

Comment: Since Bolton's aren't exactly at the best terms with the IT in the show, How did Baelish escape Bolton Patrols? Makes one wonder

Comment: It makes much more sense if Baelish went upto the Eastwatch via sea. Boltons have no see power and riding from Eastwatch to Castle Black is a much easier ride than one from Moat Cailin.

Comment: @C.Koca except if he was in the Eyrie, he would have to ride to a port (probably Gulltown) THEN sail to Eastwatch THEN ride to Mole's town. Sailing to going to take longer than riding.

Comment: @Skooba considering that it took 4-5 days from Dragonstone to the Kings Landing, you may be right. Even if it is faster, it wouldn't reduce the time much.

Answer (score 6):

In Catelyn POV in the first book we know that Lady Catelyn reached from Kings Landing to the Trident crossroads in 14 days. We learn the location at (p 277):

> "It was dark when they reached it, at the crossroads north of the confluence of the Trident."

And the time it takes at (p 280):

> "We left Kings Landing a fortnight ago, Catelyn replied, answering the safest of his questions."

In a weird way, Lady Catelyn and Ser Rodrik perfectly fits your definition. It appears the distance between Moat Cailin and Mole Town is about 2.5 times that of Kings Landing and the Crossroad Inn.

We also know that (p 278):

> "For the past week, travelers thick as flies upon the Kingsroad; knights and free riders, singers with their harps and drums, heavy wagons laden hops or corn or casks of honey, traders and craftsmen and whores and all of them moving south."

Assumptions:

1. Catelyn Stark is not a great rider.
2. They travel at the end of the summer/beginning of the autumn. It is faster than winter.
3. The roads being crowded reduces the speed.
4. The roads are in a better condition than they are in the North, simply because they are used much more often.

The assumptions 1 and 3 reduces speed while 2 and 4 increases the speed. However I tend to believe that "thick as flies" implies that effect of 3 is greater than others, so they traveled slower than someone might travel in early winter from Moat Cailin to Mole Town.

So my answer would be 20-25 days. (Page numbers may vary, depending on the edition.)

Answer (score 0):

The tongue-in-cheek answer: Exactly one week,

> if your horse is equipped with David & Dan's magical jetpack,

and only 6 days if you're Nordic!